# Flutter Firebase Streambuilder Orderby optinal value

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

```
StreamBuilder(stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection("notifications")
.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
.collection("user-notifications")
.orderBy("timestamp", descending: true)
.orderBy("postId",descending: true)
.limit(20).snapshots()
```

I have the above Firebase query where postId value does exist for some documents and does not exist for others. Is it possible to query this function without ".orderBy("postId", descending: true)"? I want the post Id field to be optional in my listview.builder.

I'd like to be able to order without the postId but I am getting an error. If I have 20 documents in that collection, I want to see them all in my listview.builder with and without postId.

At the moment, if I remove that order by postId filter, I get "the field does not exist issue" for some documents. if I keep it, I don't see the documents without the postId String.

2 example documents:

- postId: XYZ, notificationId: XYY, uid: XCC
- notificationId: ABC, , uid: ABD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to query this function without ".orderBy("postId", descending: true)"?

Yes, it is possible but you'll lose the second order.

> I want the post Id field to be optional in my listview.builder.

You cannot query a Firestore collection using an optional field. You can only return documents that do have the field on which you're performing the ordering.

> If I have 20 documents in that collection, I want to see them all in my listview.builder with and without postId.

In this case, you have to remove the call to `.orderBy("postId",descending: true)` and perform the ordering on the client.

> At the moment, if I remove that order by postId filter, I get " the field does not exist issue" for some documents.

Instead of having documents that do not have that field, you can create the field with an empty string. In this case you'll don't any errors.